# unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I've just created a new laravel project and setup the linting automation, but a lint error popped up in the return statement.

```
protected function configureRateLimiting()
{
    RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
        return Limit::perMinute(60)->by($request->user()?->id ?: $request->ip());
    });
}
```

Why the lint error pops up?

Comment: `$request->user()?->id` Why you think this is valid PHP?

Comment: @LarsStegelitz Because as of PHP 8, [it is](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.nullsafe).

Comment: Please check your PHP version. The nullsafe operator you're using was introduced in PHP 8. It is not supported on PHP 7.

Comment: If you are using PHP 8 and it's just a lint error, your linter might *think* you're using PHP 7 so you'll want to check its settings.

Answer (score 1):

Check your PHP and Laravel versions.
Laravel 9 requires PHP8.
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/releases

PHP 8 supports nullsafe operator https://kinsta.com/blog/php-8/#nullsafe-operator

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your code. Use the following code :

```
    protected function configureRateLimiting(){

    RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
        return Limit::perMinute(60)->by($request->user()->id ?: $request->ip());
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This my solve you issue. Rewrite the ternary operator as below

```
   protected function configureRateLimiting(){

     RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
     return Limit::perMinute(60)->by($request->user() ? $request->user()->id 
       : $request->ip());
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed this and issue resolved

```
protected function configureRateLimiting()
{
    RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
        return Limit::perMinute(60)->by($request->user()->id ?? $request->ip());
    });
}
```